# Will CSS3 @font-face not work with copyrighted or certain fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am having an issue trying to get `@font-face` to render fonts here. I can't seem to get it to work with Segoe (the font on WP7). The code looks correct, and I am using the latest version of Safari. I know its a copyrighted font, and it is just being used for a personal project, but i cant seem to get it to work. Can anyone help or have any suggestions?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: segoe;
  src: url('../font/segoe.ttf');
  format: 'truetype';
}

p{
  font-family: segoe;
}
```

```html
<p>testing to see if this font will render</p>
```

Comment: Are those `\`` marks on purpose or are they actually in your code?

Comment: Are those fancy quotes around the font path in the URL?

Comment: its just single quotes. ill fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `"` (double quotes) not `'` (single quotes).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: segoe;
  src: url("../font/segoe.ttf");
  format: "truetype";
}

p{
  font-family: segoe;
}
```

```html
<p>testing to see if this font will render</p>
```

Comment: that actually worked. that is really strange. i have been having this problem for a long time and gave up on @font-face. guess the browser is a bit finicky. thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @mcbeav cool mark it as answer if that worked, normally i dont use custom fonts as most user wont have them. If you want custom fonts that will work for every one then http://www.google.com/webfonts is a good option.

Comment: You shouldn't need any quotation marks at all, FWIW; the parentheses already delimit the value.  Similarly you shouldn't need to specify the format.  As for the actual question: the only problem with using copyrighted media is that someone might come along some day and yell at you for having done so.

Comment: thanks, sorry it makes you wait so many minutes and i just haven't had a chance to jump back on, thanks again for the help.